# Changing an Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm just learning android here, and Java to be honest. I'm just trying to switch to a different activity via a button click, however, it keeps crashing. It crashes when I click the button and go to make the switch. Can someone please help me figure where I'm going wrong?

First Activity:

```
package com.example.killacatoe;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.content.*;

public class TicTacToe extends Activity {//Start TicTactToe Class

//CONSTANTS

//Variables
Button mainButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tic_tac_toe);
    mainButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPlayNow);
    mainButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), playerMenu.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }   
    });
}

}//End TicTacToe Class
```

Activity I'm jumping to:

```
package com.example.killacatoe;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class playerMenu extends Activity {

    Button bOnePlayer, bTwoPlayer;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player);
        bOnePlayer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOnePlayer);
        bOnePlayer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }   
        });
        bTwoPlayer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTwoPlayer);
        bTwoPlayer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }   
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the XML for the first activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".TicTacToe" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:text="Welcome to \nTic-Tac-Toe"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bPlayNow"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="137dp"
        android:textSize="34dp"
        android:text="Play now!" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

XML for the second activity:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
         android:background="#000000"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
    />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_x="78dp"
    android:layout_y="30dp"
    android:text="GAME MODE"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="50dp" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/bOnePlayer"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="25dp"
    android:layout_y="160dp"
    android:text="Single Player"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/bTwoPlayer"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="25dp"
    android:layout_y="220dp"
    android:text="Two Player"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

    </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: In the future, please add a logcat dump. Crashing always produces an error message there, which is quite helpful for finding the issue.

Comment: Thank you, I am new on Stack overflow, I'll make sure to remember that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starting a new activity, it is necessary to add it in the manifest file.

```
<application >
    ...

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.killacatoe.playerMenu" >
    </activity>

</application>
```

then in onCreate(), for starting a new activity when the button is pressed, you can do:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.player);
    bOnePlayer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOnePlayer);
    bOnePlayer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(TicTacToe.this, playerMenu.class);
              startActivity(intent);                    

        }   
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you define playerMenu in the AndroidManifest file.

```
<application ... >
    ...
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.killacatoe.playerMenu" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Check this page for more information
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: Ahhh! I manually created my activities, I didn't realize that eclipse would automatically add this information to my manifest. I didn't even know I needed it there. Thank you, and everyone else for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you have register your PlayerMenu activity in AndroidManifest.xml ?

...

please paste the error log.

Comment: what is the difference between this answer and an answer given before that?

Answer (score 0):

use this code in  your first Activity to jump to another

```
 onClick(View v){

    Intent ps = new Intent (TicTacToe.this,
                            PlayerMenu.class);

    startActivity(ps);
      }
```

Manifest File :

```
  <Activity
           android:name="com.example.killacatoe.TicTacToe">
      </Activity>
```